# how to use opendicom.net library for dicom processing

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, dicom

Is there anyone who have used opendicom.net library for dicom image parsing. In sample code it refers below lines:

```
        DataElementDictionary dataElementDictionary = new DataElementDictionary();
        UidDictionary uidDictionary = new UidDictionary();

        try
        {
            dataElementDictionary.LoadFrom("**dicom-elements-2004.dic**",
             DictionaryFileFormat.BinaryFile);
            uidDictionary.LoadFrom("**dicom-uids-2004.dic**",
            DictionaryFileFormat.BinaryFile);

        }
        catch (Exception dictionaryException)
        {

            //Console.Error.WriteLine ("Problems processing dictionaries:\n" +  
            //   dictionaryException); 
            return;
        }
```

Where I can get the files dicom-elements-2004.dic and dicom-uids-2004.dic? I didn't get these on the website. Please help

Comment: Ok , I am able to find out the other version doc for the same but the library returns the pixeldata array of array. How it can be converted to drawble format in c# in winRT.

Comment: Are you able to compile the code as a Metro-style library? I also recommend that you rephrase the question, since you seem to have found the answer to the first question yourself.

Answer (score 3):

[openDICOM.NET](http://opendicom.sourceforge.net/) is a very simple library for DICOM file processing. The library itself is designed to be *relatively* platform-agnostic, i.e. it should be possible to build using the .NET Framework as well as Mono in various operating systems. However, out-of-the-box it is not possible to build as a WinRT/Metro library, so unless you have made substantial refactoring I assume that you have compiled the library as a regular C# class library, .NET Framework 4.5?

Assuming that you are really developing a Windows WPF or Forms application, and assuming that you have managed to read a DICOM data set using *openDICOM.NET*, you should then be able to construct a `PixelData` object:

```
var pixelData = new PixelData(dataset);
```

From the `PixelData` object you can access the pixel data as arrays of bytes:

```
byte[][] byteArray = pixelData.ToBytesArray();
```

You then need to transform the byte two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array that can be used to construct a bitmap image, by using the following properties of the `PixelData` object:

```
Rows
Columns
BitsAllocated
(BitsStored)
```

In a WPF application you should be able to create a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) object, and in Windows Forms a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e7y164x) object.

**However**, *openDICOM.NET* has not been maintained for many years, and I would strongly recommend that you use a different, more up-to-date library as the basis for your DICOM processing. For example, please have a look at the light-weight library [Evil DICOM](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com/). Here you have ready-made methods for creating a (Windows Forms) `Bitmap`, simply create a DICOM image object using the file name and immediately access the corresponding bitmap image:

```
var imageMtx = new EvilDicom.Image.ImageMatrix(name_of_dicom_file);
var dicomImage = imageMtx.GetImage(slice_numeber);
```

*Evil DICOM* currently only works for Windows Forms, but it is probably a relatively small effort to refactor the required classes to use WPF instead.

Other open-source class libraries worth exploring are [mdcm](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm) and the more recent [fo-dicom](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom), both developed by Colby Dillion. At least *mdcm* provides full WPF support.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old question but i came across this and opened a file using openDicom.NEt just now

```
 var columns = df.PixelData.Columns;
 var rows = df.PixelData.Rows;
 int displayStride = ((int)columns * PixelFormats.Gray16.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8; //truncating
 var fromArr = df.PixelData.ToBytesArray()[0];

 theImage.Source = BitmapSource.Create((int)columns, (int)rows, 96, 96,
                   PixelFormats.Gray16, null, fromArr, displayStride);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are the files that you are requesting for.

```
dataElementDictionary.LoadFrom("**dicom-elements-2004.dic**",
         DictionaryFileFormat.BinaryFile);
        uidDictionary.LoadFrom("**dicom-uids-2004.dic**",
        DictionaryFileFormat.BinaryFile);
```

It is there in the below specified path in the location 
`DicomTagSeeker-source.zip\DicomTagSeeker\bin\Debug\libraries\dictionary`

[Dicom Tag Seeker](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/580232/DicomTagSeeker-A-DiCOM-repository-tag-searcher)